# Windows 10 connects to network but no internet

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P50 with the following OS installed:-

Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
Version 1607
OS Build 14393.447

I have tried all the steps on https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/10741 but to no avail.

When I run `ipconfig` and `ping` my default gateway I get:-

```
Pinging 10.0.3.254 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.0.3.254:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

My colleagues have the same default gateway but they get a response when they ping it.

I am really at a loss of what to do next.

**Update**

When running `arp -a` I get the following:-

```
Interface: 10.0.2.182 --- 0x15
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.0.3.255            ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Comment: Please check: is your default GW MAC-address present in arp table by runing: `arp -a`

Comment: @Slipeer - thanks. I have added the information you are after.

Comment: @Slipeer - is this issue that the Default Gateway IP address is missing from this table?

Answer (score 0):

Your default gateway do not communicate with you on phisical or data link layer (or you has configured wrong ip, netmask or default gateway ip). Otherwise default gateways record would appear in the arp table immediately after the setting.

You can do:

1. Recheck network configuration
2. Check phisical connection
3. Talk to your network administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you use static then check subnet mask, else run cmd with Administrator Privileges type

netsh interface ipv4 reset

and restart pc.

Comment: @bvn63; would one of the later options in the link that the OP provided not do this behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your switch port is configured correctly for the network you need access to.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when first using Windows 10.

It turned out that the Realtek network driver that came with Windows caused this issue (network but no Internet). Installing an updated driver from the manufacturer, in my case HP, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Question... are you running Adobe Creative Cloud software? I've been having this issue for the last week, and have tracked the problem to Adobe CC, possibly AVG too. I've tried everything to fix this issue, and everything is fine, I can connect to the internet, but as soon as I open any Adobe program, it kills my internet. Even though it shows I DO have Ethernet. I'm not using WiFi, so I don't know if that would be the same issue.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Comments should be used to ask the OP questions.